# Comparing the value of columns in two dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, compare

I have two dataframe, one has unique value of `id` and other can have multiple values of different `id`.

This is dataframe `df1`:

```
id | dt| speed | stats
358899055773504 2018-07-31 18:38:34 0 [9,-1,-1,13,0,1,0]
358899055773505 2018-07-31 18:48:23 4 [8,-1,0,22,1,1,1]
```

`df2`:

```
id | dt| speed | stats
358899055773504 2018-07-31 18:38:34 0 [9,-1,-1,13,0,1,0]
358899055773505 2018-07-31 18:54:23 4 [9,0,0,22,1,1,1]
358899055773504 2018-07-31 18:58:34 0 [9,0,-1,22,0,1,0]
358899055773504 2018-07-31 18:28:34 0 [9,0,-1,22,0,1,0]
358899055773505 2018-07-31 18:38:23 4 [8,-1,0,22,1,1,1]
```

I aim to compare the second dataframe with the first dataframe and updating the values in first dataframe, only if the value of `dt` of a particular `id` of `df2` is greater than that in `df1` and if it satisfies the greater than condition then comparing the other fields as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `join` the two dataframes together to make any comparison of their columns.

What you can do is first joining the dataframes and then perform all the filtering to get a new dataframe with all rows that should be updated:

```
val diffDf = df1.as("a").join(df2.as("b"), Seq("id"))
  .filter($"b.dt" > $"a.dt")
  .filter(...)                                          // Any other filter required
  .select($"id", $"b.dt", $"b.speed", $"b.stats")
```

**Note:** In some situations it would be required to do a `groupBy(id)` or use a window function since there should only be one final row per `id` in the `diffDf` dataframe. This can be done as as follows (the example here will select the row with maximum in the speed, but it depends on the actual requirements):

```
val w = Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"speed".desc)
val diffDf2 = diffDf.withColumn("rn", row_number.over(w)).where($"rn" === 1).drop("rn")
```

More in-depth information about different approaches can be seen here: [How to max value and keep all columns (for max records per group)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636179/how-to-max-value-and-keep-all-columns-for-max-records-per-group).

---

To replace the old rows with the same `id` in the `df1` dataframe, combine the dataframes with an outer join and `coalesce`:

```
val df = df1.as("a").join(diffDf.as("b"), Seq("id"), "outer")
  .select(
    $"id", 
    coalesce($"b.dt", $"a.dt").as("dt"), 
    coalesce($"b.speed", $"a.speed").as("speed"), 
    coalesce($"b.stats", $"a.stats").as("stats")
  )
```

`coalesce` works by first trying to take the value from the `diffDf` (`b`) dataframe. If that value is null it will take the value from `df1` (`a`).

Result when only using the time filter with the provided example input dataframes:

```
+---------------+-------------------+-----+-----------------+
|             id|                 dt|speed|            stats|
+---------------+-------------------+-----+-----------------+
|358899055773504|2018-07-31 18:58:34|    0|[9,0,-1,22,0,1,0]|
|358899055773505|2018-07-31 18:54:23|    4| [9,0,0,22,1,1,1]|
+---------------+-------------------+-----+-----------------+
```

Comment: sir would this approach be efficient if we have large amount of data(let say streaming data),because join sometimes scares me.

Comment: @experiment: You would still have to do a join if you want to compare the two dataframes. However, if one of the dataframes are very small it would be possible to collect it to the driver and use it as such but then you would lose the advantage of using Spark.